# Unable logging when use logback-android

Tags: java, android, maven, logging

I am trying to change my logging library from `logback` to `logback-android` but it sounds like I've made something wrong. In my android project:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<logback>
    <configuration>
        <appender
            name="LOGCAT"
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
            <tagEncoder>
                <pattern>%logger{0}</pattern>
            </tagEncoder>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>blahblah: [%method] > %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <root level="TRACE">
            <appender-ref ref="LOGCAT"/>
        </root>
    </configuration>
</logback>

<application
    android:label="@string/custom_app_name" android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:name="blah.blah"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
</application>
```

and pom file in case 1,

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-android</artifactId>
        <version>${ch.qos.logback}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

and pom file in case 2,

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tony19</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-android-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback-android-core}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tony19</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-android-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback-android-classic}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

and in both cases

```
<properties>
    <org.slf4j>1.7.21</org.slf4j>
    <ch.qos.logback>1.0.6-1</ch.qos.logback>
    <logback-android-core>1.1.1-5</logback-android-core>
    <logback-android-classic>1.1.1-5</logback-android-classic>
</properties>
```

and the code

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Tester.class);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_tester);

    findViewById(R.id.btnTest).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            logger.debug("OK!");
        }
    });
}
```

Now if I use pom (1) (and therefore `logback`) then everything is fine and I receive the logs in LOGCAT window but if I change the dependencies to `logback-android` as shown in pom(2) nothing happens and it sounds like there is no logging any longer.

What's wrong with that?

I've set the `logback-android` configuration according to what mentioned [here](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/wiki#proguard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

due to a change in version **1.0.8-1**, `logback-android` no longer searches the `AndroidManifest.xml` by default (as an optimization). So the config must be moved to `assets/logback.xml` or [initialization search path](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/wiki#initialization-search-path) must be setup.

further information can be found [here](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/issues/120#issuecomment-226971832),